# How to use newline in Notification with antd

Tags: antd

I tried to use `\n` in my notification's decription but it did not work. what should I use instead.

```
notification.warning({
    message: 'Notification Title',
    description:
      'This is the content of the notification.\n This is the content of the notification. This is the content of the notification.',
  });
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's quite simple. Just use HTML instead of a string.

```
notification.warning({
  message: 'Notification Title',
  description: (
      <>
         This is the content of the notification.<br />
         This is the content of the notification. This is the content of the notification.
      </>
  ),  
});
```

Here I made a [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-2pj64n) for you.